# Parametric Sard-Smale theorem - when is the generic set open?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, differential-topology, morse-theory, floer-homology

I am learning Morse/Floer Theory and in my work on my master's thesis I want to apply the parametric Sard-Smale theorem. I.e. I consider a Banach bundle $\mathcal{L} \to \mathcal{M}\times \mathcal{G}$ over Banach manifolds $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ as well as a $C^{\infty}$ section $s\in \Gamma(\mathcal{L})$ such that $s \pitchfork 0_{\mathcal{L}}$ where $0_{\mathcal{L}}\subset \mathcal{L}$ denotes the 0-section. Moreover, I assume that the vertical derivative $D^v_m s_g:T_m\mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{L}_{(m,g)}$ of the section $s_g:=s(\cdot, g)\in \Gamma(\mathcal{L} \to \mathcal{M})$ is Fredholm. The parametric Sard-Smale theorem then tells me that there is a generic set $\mathcal{R}\subset \mathcal{G}$ such that for $g\in \mathcal{R}$ it holds that $s_g^{-1}(0_{\mathcal{L}})\subset \mathcal{M}$ is a finite dimensional submanifold. My question is: Under what assumptions is it true that the set $\mathcal{R}$ is also open in $\mathcal{G}$? This is true under certain conditions on the section $s$ in the classical parametric transversality theorem (see Hirsch' book on differential topology), but I have not been able to find similar conditions in the $\infty$-dimensional setting. Does anyone know such conditions or a reference?

Thanks in advance

Edit: I have been able to find various arguments in specific situations, where concrete moduli spaces are considered, but I have never been able to find a general/abstract statement, and this is really what I am hoping for.